# Как правильно делать почти одинаковые формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим у меня есть приложение с двумя таблицами. Каждая таблица имеет разные поля. В приложении есть форма для заполнения одной из таблиц. На форме есть такие элементы как `dataGridView`, `contextMenuStrip`. У каждого из этих элементов есть обработчики различных событий.

Как правильно поступить если нужно сделать вторую форму, с тем же функционалом, но для работы с другой таблицей? Первое, что приходит в голову - это создать еще одну форму, разместить те же элементы, написать те же обработчики. В крайнем случае скопировать и немного поправить код. Но, может есть более правильный подход? Ведь речь может идти не об одной-двух формах и таблицах, а о десятках.

Comment: конечно же есть, важно помнить что c# это язык ООП

Comment: @Dmitry Я догадывался об этом. :) А можно чуть подробнее, желательно с примером?

Comment: Ну вам уже ответили, передавайте настройки формы через параметры конструктора

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, сделать одну форму и при её создании или вызове передавать те или иные параметры параметры для её настройки. Так часто поступают, когда речь идёт о большом количестве однотипных форм.