# Как передать имя таблицы в функцию как параметр при создании экземпляра класса?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq

Вот в этом ([Как передать имя таблицы в функцию как параметр?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80)) посте я просил помочь разобраться с передачей имени таблицы в функцию как параметра. Мне очень помогли. Но теперь у меня встал вопрос шире.

Теперь имя таблицы нужно передавать не в функцию, а в класс, при его вызове. Идея такая:

Есть `Form1`. На ней есть `menuStrip1`. В меню три элемента. Каждый из элементов вызвает `Form2` и при вызове как-то нужно передавать туда имя таблицы.

В свою очередь `Form2`, содержащая `dataGridView1`, заполняется данными.

Чтобы это реализовать я в `Form2` создал публичный метод `BindData()`, который выполняет заполнение таблицы. И вызываю его из `Form1` каждый раз когда нужно вызвать `Form2`

```
var form2 = new Form2();
            form2.BindData(c => c.Goods);
            form2.Show();
```

**ВОПРОС**

1. Насколько такой подход правильный?
2. Есть ли более правильные решения данной задачи?

**Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void goodsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Goods = new Form2();
            Goods.BindData(c => c.Goods);
            Goods.Show();
        }

        private void goodsListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var GoodsList = new Form2();
            GoodsList.BindData(c => c.GoodsList);
            GoodsList.Show();
        }
    }
```

**Form2**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void BindData<TABLE>(Func<Context, IQueryable<TABLE>> tableSelector)
        {
            using (Context context = new Context())
            {
                var items = from Items in tableSelector(context)
                            select Items;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Модель**

```
public class Goods
{
    public int GoodsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GoodsList
{
    public int GoodsListId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Goods> Goods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GoodsList> GoodsList { get; set; }

    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>()); //Не обращайте внимания на эту строку.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если честно, код смотрится максимально паршиво, насколько это возможно.

UI не должен знать о данных в базе.

Вообще, как вы себе представляете Form2, который может отобразить произвольную таблицу? Лучше уж создать пачку специализированных форм, которые будут уметь отображать только один тип данных. И тогда данные можно просто в конструктор передавать.

Но, рассматривая именно ваш вопрос, если у вас форма максимально умная - то можно попробовать что-то вида:

```
  public partial class Form2<T> : Form
  {
    public Form2(Func<Context, IQueryable<T>> tableSelector)
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      using (Context context = new Context())
      {
        var items = from Items in tableSelector(context)
                    select Items;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
      }
    }
  }
```

Для этого надо будет поправить ещё файл Form2.Designer.cs - класс должен называться не Form2, а `Form2<T>`.

Comment: Я консультировался на этот счет [Как правильно делать почти одинаковые формы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472198/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B) и мне как раз посоветовали сделать универсальную форму. А что вы имели ввиду ***"Вообще, как вы себе представляете Form2, который может отобразить произвольную таблицу?"***. Собственно вот так и представляю, как в коде привел.

Comment: А подскажите чуть подробнее о ***"UI не должен знать о данных в базе."*** Как это достигается? Во всех учебных примерах код прямо в UI пишется.

Comment: Я не смогу дать простой ответ. Сам сейчас пишу на WPF, там используются сложные многострочные паттерны типа MVP или даже MVVM. Лучше почитать про них. В целом, код обычно выглядит так:
1. Код общения с базой данных.
2. Код, преобразующий данные из базы в данные для отображения. В вашем случае пока можно пропускать.
3. Ну и осталась форма представления - конкретно отрисованная формочка, которая ждёт строго типизированный класс (или коллекцию классов).

Comment: Насколько я успел понять то, что применимо для WPF, в частности MVP/MVVM, плохо применимо для WinForm.

Comment: Не уверен, MVP вроде применяют, сам WinForm давно не пишу.